# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input & unable to fetch data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bots

im getting this error
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

[image: Please see the image]

if i change the code the page keeps loading and loading

using next js

directory api/CreateComment

Create comment code:

```
export default async function CreateComment(req, res){

const { name, comment, _id } = JSON.parse(req.body)
console.log( name, comment, _id )

await client.config({
    token: process.env.SANITY_AUTH_TOKEN
}).create({
    _type: "comment",
    name,
    comment,
    blog:{
        _type: "reference",
        _ref: _id
    },
})
return res.status(200)
```

}

even with this error comment are fetching and storing in the backend properly.
the problem i'm facing is i'm unable to fetch them.

[image: See this]

on doing console.log i get the object in the above image

but when i try to fetch them in frontend

on running this commend

```
{JSON.stringify(comment)}
```

show the following output in my slug.js

[image: Output]

but when i do comment.name or comment[0].name i get undefined.

Reply to comment:

the form code:

```
function Form({ _id }) {
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
} = useForm();
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    
    fetch('/api/CreateComment', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ ...data, _id })
    })
}
return (<>
    <form id='my-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div data-aos='fade-right' data-aos-delay='100' className="overflow-hidden mt-8 mb-4 w-[90vh] mx-auto bg-gray-100 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
            <label htmlFor="name" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300"></label>
            <input {...register('name', { required: true })} type="text" id="name" className="mb-2 radius block p-2 w-full text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border-gray-300 sm:text-xs dark:bg-gray-800 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white" minLength={3} placeholder="Your Name" />
            {errors.name  && <p className='text32'>Name is required. Minimum length should be 3</p>}
            <div className="py-2 px-4 bg-white rounded-t-lg dark:bg-gray-800" >
                <label htmlFor="comment" className="sr-only">Your comment</label>
                <textarea {...register('comment', { required: true })} id="comment" rows="4" minLength={5} className="px-0 w-full text-sm  text-gray-900 bg-white border-0 dark:bg-gray-800 focus:ring-0 dark:text-white dark:placeholder-gray-400" placeholder="Write a comment..."></textarea>
                {errors.comment && <p className='text32'>Minimum Comment length should be 5</p>}
            </div>
            <div className="flex justify-between items-center py-2 px-3 border-t dark:border-gray-600">
                <button onClick={notify} type="submit" data-aos='fade-up' data-aos-delay='400' className="btnz inline-flex items-center py-2.5 px-4 text-xs font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-200 dark:focus:ring-blue-900 hover:bg-blue-800">
                    Post comment
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p data-aos='fade-left' data-aos-delay='700' className="h-[8vh] w-[70vh] m-auto text-xs text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Remember, contributions to this topic should follow our <a href="#" className="text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline">Community Guidelines</a>.</p>
</>
);
```

}

Comment: can you post the code of how you did the fetching?

Comment: Published the code, & to fetch in frontend i used groq const query3 = `*[_type == "blog" && slug.current == '${slug}'][0]
    {
      "comment": *[_type == "comment" && blog._ref == ^._id] | order(_createdAt desc){
        name,
        comment,
        _createdAt,
      }
    }
  `;

Comment: Next.js API routes have [built-in middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares) that will parse `req.body` based on the `Content-Type` header. Make sure to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` when making the request to your API route, and then you can simply remove the `JSON.parse` on `req.body`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `comment.name or comment[0].name on JSON.stringify(comment)` as JSON.stringify converts yous JSON data into a simple string. **To access comment.name you should not use JSON.stringify and simply do comment.name or comment[0].name**

[image]

Comment: I used json.stringify to test is my data is correct & is not null or undefined, i used comment.name to fetch data from json object showen in img no2

Comment: You should try JSON.parse(comment) and stringify, than use comment[0].name. Also you cannot do comment.name as the data fetched is of type array, to access array elements you can use  JSON.parse(comment) => comment.map(item)

Comment: when i do json.parse i get [object object] error even i tried json.stringify(json.parse(comment))

Comment: I have added a picture in answer, it will define what you are doing wrong and how to correct it